# What do the other farmers symbolize in Animal Farm?

Tags: animal-farm, george-orwell, symbolism

I asked this question on the old literature site, [it got migrated to the science fiction and fantasy site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16127/what-do-the-other-farmers-symbolize-in-animal-farm), and then was later closed as off-topic. I figured that I might as well ask the question here.

I remember reading somewhere that Mr. Pilkington, Frederick, and the other farmers in Animal Farm symbolized different countries, but I forgot which country they each symbolized. Is that true, and if it is, can someone remind me which countries the individual farmers symbolized?

Answer (score 17):

- Mr. Jones symbolizes Tsar Nicholas II, the last Tsar of Russia. He oppresses the animals, but is overthrown.
- Mr. Pilkington symbolizes England and the USA. They are frightened of the revolution.  He has a larger, but more unkempt farm compared to Frederick.
- Mr. Frederick is possibly Germany, as he's described as abusing his animals and is on bad terms with Mr. Pilkington.

Comment: Note that Frederick (as in [the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_the_Great)) and Pilkington are near-caricatures of very German and English names respectively.

Comment: Could you [edit] to flesh out this answer with some more explanation? It's not very well supported at the moment, and an answer scoring +14 should really set a better example than this :-) ([relevant recent meta post](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/987/17))